# Regex notepad++ and groups

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following data in my file:

```
234xt_
yad42_
23ft3_
45gdw_
...
```

Where the `_` means a space.
Using Notepad++ I want to rewrite it to be:

```
'234xt',
'yad42',
'23ft3',
'45gdw'
```

I am using the following regex in the "Find what" `(^\w+)\s*\n`

And in the "Replace with" field `$0`,

But it is not working as expected.

Comment: Try `$1` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^(\w+) $
```

or

```
^(\w+)\h$
```

And replace with `'$1',`.

`^` will match the start of a line, `(\w+)` will place one or more letters, digits or underscores into Group 1 (that you may access via `$1` or `\1` backreference in the replacement pattern), and then a space or `\h` will match a space or any horizontal whitespace, and then `$` will assert the position at the end of the line.

If the (white)spaces can go missing add the appropriate quantifier after the space or `\h`: `\h*` will match 0 or more whitespaces and `\h?` will match 1 or 0.

Settings & demo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `\1` instead of `$0` see the example in [the docs](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions#Example_1).